# how to specify setuptools version during build time

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am managing my dependencies using poetry and set

```
[build-system]
requires = [
"setuptools > =49.0.1",
"wheel",
```

However this does not seem to be working. I am still getting no matching distribution found for setuptools >= 40.8.0 during build time for one of my package.

My build.sh file looks like

```
release(){
   export TTOX_PARALLEL_NO_SPINNER=1
   poetry installl
   ****
}
```

the no matching distribution error pops up while poetry install is working, so maybe there is a way to specify setuptool version for poetry install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Poetry does not allow using a different build back-end than `poetry-core`, meaning that you would not be allowed to use `setuptools` in the `[build-system]` section. But I am not 100% sure, you might want to ask the Poetry maintainers directly.

You have this in your question: `setuptools > =49.0.1`. This seems incorrect to me, there should be no empty space between `>` and `=`. If I were you I would replace with `setuptools>=49.0.1`.